# Collect results from all professional competitive League Of Legends games

Tags: web-scraping, data-retrieval, riot-games-api

I am looking for a method to bulk collect all results from professional competitive League of Legends games.

I am unsure where riot keeps this data and/or the proper APIs to use to recover it.

Riot's [docs on data collect](https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/collectingdata.html) suggest I can just start scraping from a summoner name. And while this would work for collecting ladder games. The pro games are done in custom games and dont appear to be accessible.

Best.

Edit:

I am near certain it is accessible somewhere. As sites like [gol.gg](https://gol.gg/esports/home/) have the data.

Answer (score 1):

The official API does not have any endpoints for esports.

There is an API used by https://lolesports.com/, but it is not officially supported and may change at any time without warning.
There is some unofficial documentation here, but it might not be accurate or up-to-date https://vickz84259.github.io/lolesports-api-docs/

Another solution is using community-driven solutions like Leaguepedia: https://lol.gamepedia.com/Help:API_Documentation

Esports data can also be acquired from Bayes Esports (paid) https://www.bayesesports.com/